# Tyrus WebSockets (Java) - how to set client local ip address

Tags: java, websocket, grizzly, tyrus

Is there a way to specify the local ip-address and port when using WebSockets (Tyrus)?

I'm looking for the same thing you can do with the full 4 parameters constructor of [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.net.InetAddress,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int))

**EDIT**:

I have found that the low level Grizzly [TCPNIOTransport](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/nio/transport/TCPNIOTransport.html) does have a [connect() method with local-address](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/nio/transport/TCPNIOTransport.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,%20java.net.SocketAddress)), but I don't know how to make a [Tyrus Client](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.7/org/glassfish/tyrus/client/ClientManager.html) use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GrizzlyClientSocket never calls the transport connect() method with the local-address parameters.

You'll need to ask a feature request from Tyrus project, or write your own implementation of GrizzlyClientSocket, which you'll need to call from your own implementation of a GrizzlyClientContainer