# Send WebSocket request using specific IP in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, ip

I used Tyrus to make the connection. Here is the code:

```
public void connect(String IP) {
    WebSocketContainer webSocketContainer = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();

    ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator configurator = new ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator() {
        public void beforeRequest(Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
            List<String> originValue = new ArrayList<>();
            originValue.add("http://example.com");
            headers.put("Origin", originValue);
        }
    };

    ClientEndpointConfig clientConfig = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create()
            .configurator(configurator)
            .build();

    try {
        webSocketContainer.connectToServer(this, clientConfig, new URI(IP));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

My computer has a few IP addresses. I want to send a WebSocket request from selected IP - I want to bind the WebSocket to the specific local IP. Is it possible to do? Should I use another library?

EDIT: I found [netty](http://netty.io) - it allows to set the local IP address manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used proxy instead of selecting IP for the request.

Answer (score 0):

The local address will be selected by the operating system I believe - based on the routing tables in place for your local interfaces.

If you had multiple IPs that could all reach the destination host I'd suhgest you configure a (static) route to that host through the local ip you want to bind.

Comment: By default the request is always sending by one IP. I want to set the IP myself. Is this possible?

Comment: As i said - only if there's a route from that address to the server.

Comment: I think - there's another solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875927/tyrus-websockets-java-how-to-set-client-local-ip-address - but probably Tyrus doesn't support setting local IP address, and I will have to switch to another library...